# Swift 3, Xcode 8 Instantiate View Controller is not working

Tags: swift, storyboard, swift3, viewcontroller, xcode8

Xcode 8 when it compiles says to change instantiate `viewcontroller` with identifier to simply, instantiate view controller.  I did that, why does it give two errors?

I'm working with Swift 3.  I want to change pages programmatically.I've read a lot of other questions on the topic.  All of them use instantiate view controller with the identifier.  They haven't adopted the new language.

```
@IBAction func switchPage(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = 
storyboard.instantiateViewController("secondViewController") as! 
UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, 
completion: nil)    

}
```

Thanks.  I changed the code as suggested, and receive only one error:  Value of optional type 'UIStoryboard?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?  Should I add an exclamation point somewhere?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a 
nib.
}

@IBAction func ch(_ sender: UIButton) {



    let viewController = 
storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"secondViewController") as! UIViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)



}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try like this.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"secondViewController") as! UIViewController
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's close, but I'm getting one error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Aleric I have never told you to remove this line `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)` check the edited answer.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: @NiravD: will this crash the app if there isn't a viewController with that ID in the storyboard?

Comment: @3000 Yes that obvious

Comment: @NiravD: and should your code consider this possibility?

Comment: @3000 The problem in OP code is it forgot to add first parameter label `withIdentifier` it has nothing to do with the error that you are facing if you are not having identifier in your storyboard then it will crash the app

Comment: @NiravD: my comment was generic and not related to the OP issue: moreover, I've always written the same code as yours, without caring too much   :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's worked for me:

```
 let gameScene = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as UIViewController
        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = gameScene
```

Comment: This is the best granteed way 

Answer (score 3):

It's worked for me by this:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "ZWLStaticTabVc", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had forgotten to check `isInitialViewController` for my VC in storyboard. Hence it was returning nil when I called instantiateInitialViewController.
After checking that option in storyboard, the issue resolved.